# Sending request to Facebook friend has wrong message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-requests

I want to send a request to friend by web dialog. Everything is okay except a message that I have no idea comes from where!

This is my bundle:

```
private void shareToFacebook() {
        if(facebookUser != null) {

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("method", "apprequests");
            params.putString("message", facebookUser.getName() + " sent you a request in Fancied.");
            params.putString("to", facebookUser.getFacebookId());

            listener.OnFacebookRequestDialog(params);
        }
    }
```

I'm passing bundle parameter to my listener and then listener will get it and does proper things and finally dialog displays.
As you can see in attached image, there is another text message. How can I remove it or modify it.
I checked page of [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), however I didn't find any parameter useful at the end of page.

any comments or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
    params.putString("message", facebookUser.getName() + " sent you a request in Fancied.");
```

sends that text.

The large, nicely formatted text above is automatically generated by `.OnFacebookRequestDialog`

Try putting something else in your `putString` and you will see.

Comment: Exactly, Thanks. It's another reason that I hate Facebook SDK with their horrible documentation, just fk Facebook. Thanks HaIR again. More than 3 hours of mine wasted on this issue.